# How to detect browser addons in Firefox, Opera and IE?

Tags: php, javascript

How to - using either JavaScript or PHP - detect addons that are used by a user? In particular the ORBIT addon.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old question but it popped up on a google search for me. It most definitely is possible to detect browser addons. Here are a couple of resources to check out:

http://ha.ckers.org/blog/20060823/detecting-firefox-extentions/

http://webdevwonders.com/detecting-firefox-add-ons/

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can't.

Some addons (eg, Firebug) expose a client-side object model to the page, in which case you can detect them using Javascript.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  A user's installed addons is personal information and should not be available to arbitrary pages.

Comment: it should be available to make umm ethical hacking easier